# Vertical-align issue in Chrome with elements around an img inside a table-cell

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, vertical-alignment

I've found this issue only with Google Chrome : Other elements(`<strong>`, `<em>`...) than simple text, aren't well positioned while there's an `<img>` in the same line.

[image]

By the way, I tried

- `vertical-align:middle` on the `<img>`, or some `line-height`, the result is not perfect.
- The result is fine with a `vertical-align:top` for the pic, because it seems that other tags are aligned like the pic (this is crazy...). But I wish the pic to be `vertical-align:middle`...
- The result is also fine without specifying a `vertical-align` to the `table-cell`.

You can check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFYu9/1/)**

***CSS***

```
img {height:25px;}
.table {display:table;width:400px;}
.left {display:table-cell;width:30%;padding:10px;background:#CCC;}
.right {display:table-cell;width:70%;padding:10px;background:#EDEDED;
vertical-align:top;}
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="table">

    <div class="left">Left content</div>

    <div class="right">
        Some text some text, some text, some text, 
        some text, some text, some text, and a 
        <strong>bold text</strong>, then a pic : 
        <img src="some_pic_url"/>
        and <em>italic</em>
    </div>

</div>
```

It seems that other elements aligns with the bottom of the pic...

Any idea about this ugly issue, and how to fix the vertical text align correctly on any browser ?

Comment: +1, was wondering about this myself recently, having encountered [a similar problem](http://cssdesk.com/ZBaDL), with different results in [Chrome](http://i.imgur.com/iYN5G.png) as opposed to [IE10](http://i.imgur.com/s7lfc.png) and [Firefox](http://i.imgur.com/mLRfQ.png)

Comment: Yes the same smiley positioning problem. I guess that a solution should help anyone using some BBcode and smileys, or some arrows positioning... with Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a lot of solutions, it seems that the easier way to fix this problem without adding another `div` element inside the `table-cell` is to specify the `vertical-align` position to each element inside the `table-cell`.

Like adding the following :

```
.right * {vertical-align:top;}
```

In this case, the pic can keep another position than the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

The "display: table-cell"; is cascading down from the divs and applying on the contained text nodes as well, but it is not cascading to the contained strong and em nodes.

Wrap the text in a span tag and that will protect the text from getting the cascaded "display: table-cell".

Comment: `span` will not fix the problem, as you can see with Jeroen example : http://cssdesk.com/ZBaDL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug, it can be fixed by adding the same vertical alignment to image:

```
.right img {vertical-align:top;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J8ved/1/

Comment: Already tried, but if you want to have a middle vertical-align to the img, this solution doesn't works.